# How to make an Instagram GET Request?

Tags: java, android, api, get, instagram

Sorry to come in with so little information but i'm trying to make a project in which I pull from people's public Instagram accounts in order to view them.

I'm currently at the stage in which I've registered my application, and have gotten my access token with a public_content scope.

However, searching for Instagram's endpoints, I see many `GET` requests along the lines of

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I understand that I will have to replace the `ACCESS-TOKEN` part of the link with my own, but am entirely lost as to how to call this `GET` request in Java in `Android Studio`.

Any advice or points in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use Retrofit or Volley for requests.  For images, it's best to use Glide or Picasso

Comment: This might help https://github.com/ashokslsk/Instagram-Integration

Comment: That is a REST Api, so simply create your own client.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do Rest APIs. One is generic Async task but I personally find it too generalized. As an alternative, you can use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple) to do network requests from Android App.

1. Add `Volley` to `build.gradle` file:

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    }
```

2. Take `android.permission.INTERNET` permissions on your app.
3. Instantiate the Volley request queue with your app `context`:

```
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

4. Create a request for `JsonArray` or `JsonObject`:

```
    String url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=DUMMY-ACCESS-TOKEN";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // Set up operation for network callback here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

5. Add the request to volley `RequestQueue`:

```
    // queue object was instantiated in pt#3
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```